# Print specific FULL column only by range

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file which have contents like this.

```
Column1     Column2                           Column3             Column4
USER1        25 Years                          xyz zyz               123 abc
USER2        15 Years 2 months blah            abc sdsz sd        123 abc
```

and so on ...

Now what I want is to print all contents of COLUMN2 and as you can see it have dynamic contents , text can be one word or multiple words with spaces. so i need a way to print column2 contents.

Comment: How do you define the end of column 2? Does it have a fixed width?

Comment: 2nd column does not have fixed width, example the output can be like
this is 2nd column text example OR
this is 2nd column OR
this is 2nd text OR
2nd

so how can i print out all text in second column only?

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1{b=index($0,$2); e=index($0,$3)} {print substr($0,b,e-b)}' file
```

If the `age` fields length is dynamic, you first have to find out where it begins and where it ends. The `b` variable defines the character where the field begins and the `e` varibale the end. `substr()` then cuts the string in the desired length.

Comment: but like i said i want to print column2 and it have variable length so cutting specific range may not be suitable,example username can be long, age can be shorter or longer so i want a way to print AGE column fully

Comment: @SyedJahanzaib See my updated answer

Comment: No bro its not working.

Comment: @SyedJahanzaib can you then give my a bit more info? Error mesaage? awk version? For me it's working with mawk version `1.3.3` and gawk version `3.1.8` and your demo file.

Comment: I have edited the question to provide more clarity.
Demo file have contents like this.

`Column1     Column2                           Column3             Column4
USER1        25 Years                           xyz zyz               123 abc
USER2        15 Years 2 months blah    abc sdsz sd        123 abc`

Now what I want to print all contents of COLUMN2 and as you can see it have dynamic contents , text can be one word or multiple words with spaces. so i need a way to print column2 contents.

Comment: @SyedJahanzaib Nothing changed, it still works with my solution. What is your awk version? Operating system? Error message? I cannot help you without such infos, if it's not working.